# how can i get first element in body index wise in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get first element or any element of body using index

```
<body>
  <div id="popUpWindow" style="width: 500px; height: 200px; background-color: red; "></div>    
  <button id="myButton">ClickOn</button>
</body>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var elem = $('body')[0];
  console.log(elem);
});
```

I am able to get body as first with [0] index, Next I want to get the div or button in the body with the same way, I know there is a way of doing it with first child but I want to do it this way. In jquery only please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the child selector or descendant selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var elem = $('body').children().first().get(0);
  console.log(elem);
});
```

Adding the [`.get(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) will get the [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), if not, it would be jQuery [`Object`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Object).

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var elem = $('body').children().first().get(0);
  console.log(elem);
});
```

```html
<div>I guess I am first object?</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you open up the **console** and see, you can find the `<div>` element, being output:

[image]

Comment: is there a way to get it like $('body').children().get(15);

Comment: @mohsin Yes, that's the idea. This is how it works, and it gets the 15th element. Read about [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) and you will know.

Comment: @mohsin See the screenshot!

Comment: Ok I got that, If I want the attribute of that elem, I should say $('body').children().get(15).attr('id'); ?

Comment: @mohsin Yes, and `$('body').children().eq(15).attr('id');` should work. Coz when you use `.get()`, it gives the JS equivalent. Does it help?

Comment: @mohsin You are welcome buddy. Lemme know if you are stuck at some point.